# parameter still pending-reboot after reboot or restart

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In RDS, postgresql 9.4, I tried to upgrade some parameters in a parameter group: pg_stat_statements.track, shared_preload_libraries and track_activity_query_size. As it described, since the last two parameters are static, so I need to reboot the DB instance. But what is wired is that even I reboot or restart the instance, the parameters are still in 'pending-reboot'

```
> C:\>aws rds describe-db-parameters --db-parameter-group-name
> pcore-production - source user {
>     "Parameters": [
>         {
>             "ApplyMethod": "immediate",
>             "Description": "Selects which statements are tracked by pg_stat_sta ements.",
>             "DataType": "string",
>             "IsModifiable": true,
>             "AllowedValues": "NONE,TOP,ALL",
>             "Source": "user",
>             "ParameterValue": "ALL",
>             "ParameterName": "pg_stat_statements.track",
>             "ApplyType": "dynamic"
>         },
>         {
>             "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot",
>             "Description": "Lists shared libraries to preload into server.",
>             "DataType": "string",
>             "IsModifiable": true,
>             "AllowedValues": "pg_stat_statements",
>             "Source": "user",
>             "ParameterValue": "pg_stat_statements",
>             "ParameterName": "shared_preload_libraries",
>             "ApplyType": "static"
>         },
>         {
>             "ApplyMethod": "pending-reboot",
>             "Description": "Sets the size reserved for pg_stat_activity.current query, in bytes.",
>             "DataType": "integer",
>             "IsModifiable": true,
>             "AllowedValues": "100-102400",
>             "Source": "user",
>             "ParameterValue": "2048",
>             "ParameterName": "track_activity_query_size",
>             "ApplyType": "static"
>         }
>     ] }
```